# Parsing an Input Regarding a Directed Graph

Tags: java, parsing, graph

I am working on a problem where I have run into a slight delay. I am working with directed graphs and trying to determine if within a certain input, if the route to get there exists. Now my issue is that I have to enter the input in one string, but it has to be parsed the way it is to pull out important information. For example:

you have a problem instance of   where G is a directed graph with a path from s to t (nodes)

And my input string would be: (1,2,3,4,5),((1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,5),(4,3),(5,2)),1,5

The first set of parentheses represents the nodes, the second set represents the make up of the graph and routes, where as the number 1 would represent s and 5 would represent t (last two numbers at the end).

I have to implement a program to determine whether or not the path exists. The problem lies with the parsing though. I need to extract the list of nodes (first parentheses), list of edges (second set), the starting node(1) and ending node(5).

Can anyone offer me some insight on how to parse these and break them up in such a way where I can extract and print out these? I am not looking for a full out written working program by any means, just clarification and maybe code snippets to point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the input would strictly follow the format you provided, then this is simply a parsing problem. Here is how you get the three big blocks (vertices, edges and st).

```
 String input=" (1,2,3,4,5),((1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,5),(4,3),(5,2)),1,5";

String nodes=input.substring(0, input.indexOf("((")-1).trim();
String edges=input.substring(input.indexOf("((")+1, input.indexOf("))")+1).trim();
String st=input.substring(input.indexOf("))")+3).trim();
```

You can then parse every block alone and get its values. One thing: the list of edges is enough for defining the graph (you really do not need the first block).

EDIT: 
You can simply initialize a boolean array `visited[]` with size equal to the number of vertices. Initially, all vertices are not visited.

Comment: Hey @Xline thanks for your response! I was actually unaware of the trim functionality until just now. This definitely helped me out though. I wish I could take out the first block, however, it's a requirement unfortunately.

Comment: I just have another question though. How would I go about marking each node as visited and setting up the initial design for this? I am not familiar at all with Directed graphs and the input of this is really strange. Is there a skeleton at all?

Comment: I understand what you are saying now, thanks. So something like Boolean[] visited = new Boolean[n] where n is the number of vertices? My main concern though now is actually taking that input and using it in such a way where I can break each vertice into it's own so to say. For example, how would I take vertice 1->2 (1,2) and then do 1->3 (1,3) given the input I have to deal with? I'm just stuck on how to actually implement a structure to deal with this. I just can't thing of something that would work.

Comment: any ideas on how to go about this? Thanks